# Can you use cooked fish heads and bones in stock?

Tags: fish, stock

Is there any reason not to put the heads and bones from cooked fish in stock?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, go ahead. I do it all the time, and in fact some stock recipes call for roasted bones. Just make sure to store the heads/bones safely to keep a nice taste between the original cooking and the stock-making.

If you season the fish heavily during the original cooking, it may influence the taste of the stock.